# The Two HTTP Connection Limit Issue

Tags: http

Can anyone provide any resources as to how I can handle this? I've noticed Facebook has someone managed to detect how many tabs are open on my computer. I had 3 conncurent tabs open in Chrome, and only 2 were 'pulling' data.

This isn't a question about Facebook,and it doesn't have any code. I'm looking for some common techniques that have solved this problem. Feel free to downvote / vote to close. Its your personal choice.

Comment: I don't think you've described the problem adequately, for anyone to suggest techniques to solve it. Older browsers used to limit connections on a per-site basis to only two, based on a recommendation in the HTTP RFC, but modern browsers have raised the limit.

Comment: I've been reading this: http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue